# Open Call Hierarchy fails in Eclipse on class functions

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I run C++ project on Eclipse Oxygen2 in Ubuntu14.06. When I do `Open Call Hierarchy` on class functions I have message `Cannot resolve selected text to a defined function or member` in status bar and no hierarchy displayed. Navigation with `ctrl+click` also not works between class functions while non class function works fine. How to solve these problems?

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is without a code example.

Comment: Was the project compilable at the time when you tried `Open Call Hierarchy`? Have you tried to rebuild the index?

Comment: Yes, code is compilable and yes, I tried to rebuild index.

Answer (score 0):

Run C/C++ Code Analysis.
Right Click on the project -> C/C++ Code Analysis[image]

This worked for me.